# How do I disable Flash caching?

Tags: flash, caching, actionscript

I have a flash application and I want my users not to be able to do caching in their flash players.
I couldn't find the code that disables the option of caching for them.

Does anyone have the line I need to add (and where) which will disable the flash caching?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean. Do you want to make the client not store the flash file on their computers?

Answer (score 0):

In your html code, add

```
<meta http-equiv=”pragma” content=”no-cache” />
```

to the `<head>` element.